# Como puedo pedir al usuario que ingrese el tamaño de un vector?

Tags: array, pseint, vectores, sl

Estoy haciendo un algoritmo para generar un vector con valores enteros aleatorios de **N** posiciones, donde **N** debe ser leido por teclado. El codigo me arroja un error en la **linea 3**, en la **declaracion de variables**. El error dice: **Error : `n' no es  una constante**. Estoy utilizando el lenguaje de programacion **SL** de **CNC** y el software **SLE2** para hacer el algoritmo. Tambien, puede hacerse en **PSeInt**. Con este algoritmo yo espero obtener el tamaño del vector que se ha asignado y los valor aleatorios dentro de ese vector.

Estuve intentado asignarle una constante al valor '**N**'. Pero no me resulto...

```
var
    i, n : numerico 
    arreglo : vector[n] numerico 

inicio 
    cls()

    i = 0
    n = 0

    imprimir ("Ingrese el tamaño del vector: ")
    leer(n)

    repetir 
        arreglo[i] = random(100)
        i = i + 1
    hasta (i <= n)

    desde i = 1 hasta n
    {
        imprimir (arreglo[i])
    }
fin
```

Comment: no conozco el lenguaje, pero si estas definiendo un vector, la mayoria de los lenguajes necesita saber el tamaño antes de la asignacion, si no, como asigna el tamaño???? revisa la documentacion del lenguaje para tamaños de array. en muchos casos no se puede hacer y tienes que recurrir a otras estructuras...